# SQL query - Left Joins

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables, one has a list of all products and banding and the 2nd table has product and prices. I have joined the two table and what I need to find out is that based on the band what is the highest selling product.
[image]

When I join the 2 tables and use the below query

[image]

I am getting a total value rather than a split by Band. Is there any way i can get a band split.
[image]

What I am after, is something like the below where the query identifies only the top sold product within the band.
[image]

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of aggregation, sometimes the window functions like ROW_NUMBER come in handy.

ROW_NUMBER can calculate a sequencial number based on an order.
Then it can be used to filter on.

```
select Band, Product
, UniPrice as "High Selling"
from
(
  select
    prod.Band
  , prod.Product
  , prod.PipelineID
  , price.UniPrice
  , row_number() over (partition by prod.Band order by price.UniPrice desc) as rn
  from Table1 prod
  left join Table2 price 
         on price.PipelineID = prod.PipelineID
  where prod.Band is not null
) q
where rn = 1
order by Band;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> Band | Product   | High Selling
> :--- | :-------- | -----------:
> A    | SIM0      |          4.5
> B    | B2B       |           30
> C    | Iphone 11 |          850
> D    | Nokia A10 |          600
> ```

**Extra:**

If row_number hasn't been implemented on the sqlite version, then a correlated sub-query could be used instead.

```
select Band
, MAX(Product) AS Product
, MAX(UniPrice) as "High Selling"
from
(
  select
    prod.Band
  , prod.Product
  , prod.PipelineID
  , price.UniPrice
  , (select max(price2.UniPrice)
     from Table1 prod2
     join Table2 price2 
       on price2.PipelineID = prod2.PipelineID
     where prod2.Band = prod.Band) as MaxBandPrice
  from Table1 prod
  left join Table2 price 
    on price.PipelineID = prod.PipelineID
  where prod.Band is not null
) q 
where UniPrice = MaxBandPrice
group by Band
order by Band;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=63462103080078895a8848f75af2e51d)*

Comment: This is not working, i get an error

Comment: @user14140366 I had tested on db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4978d613f0c9331583cbc035b0a7801d)  So what's the error you had?

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. Is there a way i can get the results without the over partition

Comment: @user14140366 Added an extra solution, but it ain't pretty.

Comment: where are you getting 'prod' from. My table name is Table 1 and table 2 and then further down you have prod2. Sorry, i am confused

Comment: Changed it again, calculating a MaxUniPrice now.  prod, price, prod2, price2 are just table alias names.  Sometimes tables have long names. Aliases make it more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239186/discussion-between-user14140366-and-lukstorms).

Comment: Hey, I am still confused, where did you get the 2nd table from(prod, price, prod2, price2 ) is that a replacement for my table names. Table 1 and table 2?

Comment: Both queries are not working, the 1st one is giving me incorrect info and the 2nd query is giving me a whole list instead of grouping it by Band